# How to Group by month when there's a turn of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table  with this template:

Table_1

```
+----------+------------------+-----+
| Code     |     DateTime     | Qty |
+----------+------------------+-----+
|        1 |08/31/2019 18:30  | 100 |
|        1 |09/01/2019 18:30  | 150 |
|        2 |09/03/2019 18:30  |  80 |
|        2 |09/03/2019 18:30  | 100 |
|        3 |10/15/2019 18:30  | 100 |
+----------+------------------+-----+
```

And I need to group by Code, Year, Month and sum(Qty).

I've already made the select for this table :

```
Select
    Year(DateTime) as Year,
    DATENAME(Month,Datetime) as Month,
    CODE,
    SUM(QTY) as Qty,

From 
    Table_1

Group by 
    Code,
    Year(DateTime),
    DATENAME(Month,Datetime)

Order by Code
```

but when a Code has datetime in two differents months, that Code has two rows:

```
+----+-----------+-=---+-----+
|Year|   Month   |Code | Qty |
+----+-----------+-----+-----+
|2019| August    |  1  | 100 |
|2019| September |  1  | 150 |
|2019| September |  2  | 180 |
|2019| October   |  3  | 100 |
+----+-----------+-----+-----+
```

How can get group by Code, in that case with rows in more than one months,
considering the last one month, like:

```
+----+-----------+-=---+-----+
|Year|   Month   |Code | Qty |
+----+-----------+-----+-----+
|2019| September |  1  | 250 |
|2019| September |  2  | 180 |
|2019| October   |  3  | 100 |
+----+-----------+-----+-----+
```

Hope I was clear.

Comment: Looks like you want to use MAX month and not group by it.

Comment: *"but when a Code has datetime in two differents months, that Code has two rows"* but that makes sense. The `SUM` for Code `1` in September *was* 150, not 250..

Comment: @SeanLange But months are not alphabetical

Comment: but `DATENAME(MONTH,MAX(Yourdate))` is @JoelCoehoorn ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I realize that. Looks like they want the most recent month.

Comment: @Larnu exactly!!!

Comment: Then don't group by month.

Comment: @larnu "but that makes sense". I know, when I made the select, I didn't think case one code has two months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only group by Code. The trick here is showing the correct month and day afterwards. The easiest way to do this is via nested queries:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(Month) As Year, 
    DATENAME(Month, Month) AS Month, 
    Code, 
    Qty
FROM (
    SELECT
        CODE, 
        MAX([Datetime]) As Month,
        SUM(QTY) as Qty
    FROM
        Table_1    
    GROUP BY 
        Code 
) t    
ORDER BY Code
```

This would a little harder if you also only wanted the Qty from that month, but since you still `SUM()` all months we can still get by with simple aggregation.

Comment: `DATENAME(Month, Month) AS Month` >_< 3 Month's, all with different meanings, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT YEAR(A.MX_MONTH) Yr,
DATENAME(Month,A.MX_MONTH) Mn,
A.Code Code,
SUM(A.Qty) Qty  
FROM(
    SELECT *,MAX(DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Code) MX_MONTH
    FROM your_table
)A
GROUP BY A.Code,YEAR(A.MX_MONTH),DATENAME(Month,A.MX_MONTH)
```

Output is-

```
Yr      Mn          Code    Qty
2019    September   1       250
2019    September   2       180
2019    October     3       100
```

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93f5476809ee4897dafeb95568471ef6)